# Java http server rps limitation

Tags: java, threadpool

I wrote a simple and light http server in java, with a thread pool (size=2048) to handle requests. In average each (request,respond) content-data length is (500, 5000) bytes

It work great for my work with 15K(rps) of load-test result.
But it seems there would be much higher rps, because usage of each server's cpu is < 10% during the load-test, no busy moment.

I tried to increase thread pool size to 4096 (did it for server's backlog too) or even higher but it didn't really change, I can't pass 16K rps load-test.

Maybe something I implemented has limitation cause this rps? Which one could be?

Comment: Maybe the limit is just your network throughput? 15Krps x 5000 bytes = about 70 MB per second.

Comment: Ahhh dammnnn, pretty simple. You're right, thanks